# How to configure Spring Boot application to use AWS Secrets manager VPC endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager

I have integrated my Spring boot application with spring cloud aws secrets manager config and it's working. Now, i want the application to use Secrets Manager VPC endpoint instead of public endpoint. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Spring boot, however, I suspect there should be no changes to your Spring boot config.

When you add a VPC endpoint, you have the option to use ["Private DNS"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html). What this does is changes DNS within the VPC so that all requests for the Secrets Manager endpoint use the VPC endpoint address. This makes the change transparent to your application.

Just turn on VPC endpoints with private DNS and you should be good to go.